# Trying to change title of JFrame from a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, jframe

When I am trying to set the title of my JFrame from a Thread using a function I made in the same class as my JFrame:

```
public  void setTheTitle(String newTitle)
{
    this.setTitle(newTitle);
}
```

In my Thread, I try to use the function by doing:

```
Main.setTitle(schar1 + schar2 + "-Resistance-" + schar3 + schar4);
```

(Main is the name of my class, and schar1, shcar2, schar3, and schar4 are variables deifned earlier in the Thread)

When I do this, it says that I cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setTitle(String) from the type Frame. So I changed the function to this:

```
public static void setTheTitle(String newTitle)
{
    this.setTitle(newTitle);
}
```

And this now gives me the error that I cannot use this in a static context. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Format your question or nobody is going to read it...

Comment: Block of text and unformatted code - this question does not look good. More importantly **never change or otherwise interact with Swing components outside of the EDT**. Maybe start with the [Oracle tutorial on the topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: You can't use `this` inside a `static` function... Basic 101 programming knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

This is my best bet - considering the amount of code given - try setting the JFrame instead of extending it

```
private JFrame jf = new JFrame("First Title");
```

and access the title from that method

```
jf.setTitle(newTitle);
```